# google Places Autocomplete dropdown not triggering 'place_changed' event in iOS9 using ionic3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-places-api

This is the sample code , Very basic , but 'place_changed' is not triggering in iOS

```
var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
            mylocation = autocomplete.getPlace();
            alert(mylocation);
        })
```

tried these solutions :

1 : removed **autocomplete** from listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener('place_changed', function()
```

2 :  added **tappable** because of pac-item is not a button , link .

```
let list1 = document.querySelectorAll(".pac-item,.pac-container");

     console.log('pacIt', list1);

     for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; ++i) {
         list1[i].setAttribute('tappable', 'true');
     }
```

3: added **needsclick**

```
 let list2 = document.querySelectorAll(".pac-item, .pac-item span");

     console.log('pacIt', list2);

     for (let i = 0; i < list2.length; ++i) {
        list2[i].classList.add('needsclick');
    }
```

And none of the solutions helped me to solve the issue.

Kindly anyone is having clean fix , please share .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Bug fix from Google

Hence created my own custom autocomplete

first, init the component :

```
this.customAutoComp = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(
                {
                    componentRestrictions: { 'country': 'in' }
                });
```

Next

```
 this.customAutoComp.getQueryPredictions({ input: value }, (results, status) => {


                            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

console.log(results); 
        }
    });
```

Results will be populated on UI using UL, LI or any other cards style.

Click on Any address

```
public clickAddress(address) {

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

 console.log(results);
}
});
```